# Add_menu_page and saving settings

Tags: plugin-development, options, settings-api

I am working on an WP plugin and have my settings in a created menu page. When I save the page my settings are saved without any problems, but I don't return to the settings page but to a page where you can see all settings that exists in WordPress.

How can I return the user to my own settings page?

I post to `options.php` as described in the help docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) or hook a function to admin_init that checks permissions and nonces, saves the updated values and redirects to your settings page.